# First Post Learning Python - Working on Exercises

Tags: python-3.x

So, my exercise ask me to get inputs from the user (integer) and break the process of getting numbers once the user types "done".  Then the desired output should be:

> Smallest number =
>   Largest number =

**Problem is:**

I set 2 variables *smallest* and *largest* this way:

```
smallest = None
largest =  None
```

But when i try to compare the user input with theses variables i get an error " `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'`,  I tried casting the string to int an still getting the same error.

Can someone help me?  Thanks,

My code so far:

```
largest = None
Smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done": break
    try:
        val = float(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
    number = int(num)
    if number > largest:
        largest =number
```

[king](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVOtI.png)

Comment: Think about where you are setting `largest` to a value and how your code gets to that point.

Comment: None is a type & its not a integer or number. If you want to compare , largest must have a value like 0 or something. Again if you have negative values its not the way

Answer (score 0):

When the first valid input comes, the variable `number` is an `int` while the variable `largest` is still `None`. You try to compare them with '>' operator, that's why the error is thrown.

You can set the initial value of largest/smallest as the first valid number.

Comment: Thank you Kang. It´s all set now.  Thanks